# Delete every other element from a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

I need to take an array and remove every second element from the array. Always keep the first element and start removing with the next element.
Example:

```
["Keep", "Remove", "Keep", "Remove", "Keep", ...] --> ["Keep", "Keep", "Keep"]
```

None of the arrays will be empty.

I figured that the element to be removed must have an odd index and tried to solve this problem using a for-loop and modulo:

```py
def remove_every_other():
    for element in my_list:
        if my_list.index(element) % 2 != 0:
            my_list.remove(element)
    return my_list
```

When I run my code with the following lists:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
my_list2 = ["hello", "goodbye", "hello again"]
my_list3 = [[1, 2], [1, 2]]
my_list4 = [["goodbye"], {"Great": "Job"}, ["Goodbye"]]
```

These are the results when I run my code and print the lists afterwards:

```
['hello', 'hello again']
[1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
[['goodbye'], ['Goodbye']]
```

It seems odd to me that the code works for a list of strings (`my_list2`) as well as for a list of lists but (`my_list4`) but not if the list of lists contains integers instead of strings inside the inner lists (`my_list3`) or if it is a list containing integers instead of strings (`my_list`).

Does Python treat lists differently depending on their contents? I feel like that should not matter here since I am checking the indexes of the elements and not the values itself.

I'm using Python `3`.

Comment: Try doing `my_list[::2]`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it) help you?

Comment: Btw, it "seems" to work for the list of string, but it's a special case because the list has just 3 elements. i.e. not because of type, but because the length of the original list is 3

Comment: Okay I mostly got where I was thinking wrong, thanks a lot! Why doesn't the code work for a list with 2 elements though? In this case the modifying of the list shouldn't mess with the indices right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the side effects of *mutating* the list you are iterating over.

For the example of `my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

When you reach your first odd index, you are *altering* the exact list you continue to iterate over. Your new list looks like this:

`[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

You've changed the size! This means all the indexes are different, and the for loop continues onto the following index. This *is* hard to reason about.

Often, it's conceptually simpler and less error-prone to build a *new list* with the values you want. Maybe something like:

```py
def remove_every_other(my_list):
    new_list = []
    # enumerate is a pythonic alternative for doing your my_list.index(element) idea
    for idx, element in enumerate(my_list):
        if idx % 2 == 0:
            new_list.append(element)
    return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by removing that value whose index is an odd number.

````
def rem_odd_index_value(my_list):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if i%2==0:
            result.append(my_list[i])
    return result

print(rem_odd_index(my_list3))```
````